# stancl/tenancy: Check from central if tenant db already exists

Tags: laravel, postgresql, multi-tenant

I'm using stancl/tenancy for multitenancy with multiple databases. What I need to do is to check while being on my central page, if a (wanna-be-tenant-)db already exists.

When trying to create a new tenant, the package use DatabaseManager->ensureTenantCanBeCreated($tenant), so I'm trying to do something similar but before the creation of tenant, so I can prevent getting 'Database already exists' on my tenant creation.

Answer (score 1):

If I don't misunderstand the problem, the solution is as follows; `Schema::hasTable('mytable'); //boolean`

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the problem, 'hasTable' is looking for a table inside the Database, and I want to look for the Database itself. Thanks for the answer though